# Visual studio 2010 Bing Map location finder by longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am creating a windows 7 phone application which able to search for location by name of location. Now my problem is that i can't locate the current location and the bing map is unable to search for the location.

I am using visual studio 2010 c sharp coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Bing Locations API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff701715.aspx) to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a location specified by name. There is a REST API that can provide responses in JSON or XML and there is also a SOAP API (just navigate through the docs to find the SOAP API reference). For example, this request does a lookup for location information by street in the US:

`http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/US/WA/98052/Redmond/1 Microsoft Way?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey`

To start working with the Bing Maps REST Services, you must have a Bing Maps Key. To get a Bing Maps Key, take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx).

Comment: is it possible for me to do something like this? http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/dinesh/archive/2010/08/05/how-to-find-geographical-coordinates-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Yes, same API slightly different request. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff701714.aspx

Comment: thank you, but i still don't have idea on how do i get started with the location api. Can you help me?

Comment: I've posted links to articles that walk through using the Bing Maps REST service and the documentation for the Bing Locations service, which works in exactly the same way. What else do you need?

Comment: is there any sample or source code available? i really do not know how to get started. So sorry, i am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

Or check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/Resco-Location-Library.aspx) describing the use of the Resco Location Library. (Self promoting, sorry.) GeoCode class should help.